# laravel Barryvdh dompdf error layout_line()

Tags: laravel, dompdf, php-8.1, barryvdh

Im using Laravel 8, codes works perfectly before in both dev and prod server before. but when i move to PHP8, it still works in Dev server, but got an error in my production environment with this message

```
TypeError
Dompdf\FrameReflower\Text::layout_line(): Argument #1 ($block) must be of type Dompdf\FrameDecorator\Block, null given, called in /home/aliseafo/ali/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/FrameReflower/Text.php on line 399
```

below is the sample code, even with this simple codes, it still got the error

```
<!doctype html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Invoice - 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div>
                <h1 align="center">COMMERCIAL INVOICE</h1>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
    </html>
```

latest config:

- Development PHP 8.1.6, Laravel 8.83, Laravel dompdf 2.0
- Production PHP 8.1.8, Laravel 8.83, Laravel dompdf 2.0

but still got that error.

anyone experiencing this before, or any clue why and how?

thanks for any ideas

Did this attempt, but still got error:
already tried

1. php artisan cache:clear; php artisan config:cache
2. reinstall laravel dompdf both in dev or prod composer update
3. recopy all files from dev to prod directly
4. php-mbstring enabled already
5. charset=utf-8 already added in the templates

Update 1.
when im switched it back to PHP7.4, nothing changed with the code, and it can print the pdf file successfully. so i think there is something problem with between my php8.1 installation or the compatibility of laravel-dompdf with php8.1